# Apache a2ensite default settings

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have set up VirtualHost files from scratch before and only recently come over the a2ensite command. I think this is a great command and very useful, but most of my sites configured have the same settings (such as ssl certs, basic auth etc).

Is there a way I can change what a2ensite writes to in my sites-enabled directory when I use it? For example, automatically putting my ssl certs in, etc.

Cheers

P.S. On 11.04 Ubuntu Server with Apache2 installed. Permissions to install further software.

Comment: The a2ensite script just creates a link to the existing config file in the sites-available directory. It doesn't actually write a new file. This link may be useful to you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a2ensite` only creates the correct symlink in `sites-enabled` to allow the site configured in `sites-available` to be served.

Comment: Don't forget the helpful reminder to reload Apache. :-)